# Is it still safe to use my pi? Missing component (capacitor?) near USB port

Tags: hardware, pi-3b+

I dropped my pi and what I think is a capacitor has come off. What effect will this have on the USB ports, if any? Can I get away with just not using them?

[image]

Comment: Not answering your direction question, if you still have that part, you could probably reattach it and proceed from there. Look up "surface mount" for ways to do this.  It does require a little skill and some tools, but it's probably not wickedly hard.  Especially if you determine that your board is otherwise unusable so that you have nothing to lose.

Comment: Based on its location, I do not *think* it is a vital component. So if you run out of better options, it would probably be OK to keep using it, as opposed to trash it. Worst case is a fried Pi.

Comment: The "standard" USB circuit uses bypass ~220n x 2: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=138280. The caps are there to make the power stable.  Should work and safe to use Rpi without them.